# /usr/bin/time, interpret the output

Tags: linux, cpu-time

I wanted to record the cpu time of running some programs, I put /usr/bin/time command in from the the command, like the following:

```
/usr/bin/time command_name_and_args
```

the result I got as follow:

```
652.25user 5.29system 11:53.85elapsed 92%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 5109232maxresident)k
3800352inputs+1620608outputs (2major+319449minor)pagefaults 0swaps
```

would it be correct for the **cpu time**  is 652.25 + 5.29 = **657.54 seconds**?

and does **11:53.85elapsed** mean 11 minutes 53.85 seconds on wall clock?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exactly. CPU time might exceed wall clock time if you have more than one thread.